# Caching Rust/Wasm tools in Gitlab CI?

Tags: rust, gitlab, gitlab-ci, rust-wasm

I'm working with Wasm and Rust, and I'm deploying the page with gitlab pages.

I'm using a gitlab-ci.yml file that looks like this:

```yaml
image: "rust:latest"

variables:
  PUBLIC_URL: "/repo-name"

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
    - cargo install wasm-pack
    - wasm-pack build --target web
    - mkdir public
    - mv ./pkg ./public/pkg
    - cp ./index.html ./public/index.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

But even for a "Hello World" app, this takes ~12 minutes.

~11 minutes of that is taken by the `cargo install wasm-pack` step.

Is there any way I can cache the intermediate step, to avoid doing this every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page: [Caching in GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) talks about caching and/or using artifacts to persist files between jobs. You may be able to make use of that.

It then becomes a question of how to get `cargo install` to use that cache or the saved artifacts.

Alternatively, you can define your own base build image (run the `cargo install` steps in that), and store that in Gitlab's docker registry; see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/.

Comment: "how to get cargo install to use that cache or the saved artifacts." — Try `CARGO_TARGET_DIR=$(pwd)/target cargo install wasm-pack` so that the build files are put in the same directory as the rest of what you're caching. That helped for my (GitHub) CI cache setup.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to cache `$CARGO_HOME` (downloaded sources) and `$CARGO_TARGET_DIR` (built targets).

Note that you need to add `$CARGO_HOME/bin` to your `$PATH` or call binaries from there directly.

Your example would look as follows:

```yaml
pages:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    CARGO_HOME: .cargo
    CARGO_TARGET_DIR: cargo-install
  cache:
    paths:
      - .cargo
      - cargo-install
  script:
    - rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
    - cargo install wasm-pack
    - .cargo/bin/wasm-pack build --target web
    - mkdir public
    - mv ./pkg ./public/pkg
    - cp ./index.html ./public/index.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```